# Difference in two Elasticsearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone please point me the **differences between this two queries**?

```
'filtered': {
  'filter': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        { 'query': { 'match': { '_all':  query } } },
        { 'term': { 'status': true } },
        { 'range': { 'published_at': { 'lte': 'now' } } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
'filtered': {
  'query': {
    'match': { '_all':  query }
  },
  'filter': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        { 'term': { 'status': true } },
        { 'range': { 'published_at': { 'lte': 'now' } } }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Coming from a MySQL background, it would be something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (fields) AGAINST (query) AND status=1 AND published_at <= NOW()`

Also, i've been messing with filters, bools, queries, terms for more than i can handle so maybe i'm doing it just plainly wrong. There is any better method?

Comment: Have you read the first paragraph of the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide) for [Filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filters.html#query-dsl-filters) and [Queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html#query-dsl-queries) explaining the differences between the two?

Comment: Right, i missed that part, thx.

Comment: Since filters are not affected by analyzer, should i use `index: not_analyzed` in status and published_at fields?

Comment: That depends on your use case I'd say. If you ONLY need to perform a boolean "yes/no" filter query on this field, I'd say yes. Otherwise don't bother too much about that for the beginning. Not sure if you should put the date field not_analyzed, though.